# Convert nested select to join

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT bank.bank_name, 
   (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(account.balance),0) 
   FROM account 
   WHERE account.bank_name = bank.bank_name 
       AND account.account_type = 'loan') AS total 
FROM bank
```

Account Table:

[image]

Comment: Then function `OALESCE` is unknow in SQL, You should REVIEW YOUR QUESTION  (by using [edit]). and please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: `OALESCE` seems to have been an artifact of the edit done by Billai Begueradj.

Comment: I'm getting the exact result that is required, I just need to convert this query to Join, as I have to use joins only.

Comment: @MMohsinMahar: what did you try yourself to convert this query ?

Comment: I have 2 tables, bank & account. I need to calculate the sum of the balance from account table for all accounts for each bank that is present in the bank table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is probably more efficient than a `join`/`group by` version, but it is equivalent to:

```
SELECT b.bank_name, COALESCE(SUM(a.balance), 0) as total 
FROM bank b LEFT JOIN
     account a
     ON a.bank_name = b.bank_name AND a.account_type = 'loan'
GROUP BY b.bank_name;
```

I should note that if all banks have loans (which seems reasonable) no `JOIN` is necessary:

```
SELECT a.bank_name, SUM(a.balance as total 
FROM account a
WHERE a.account_type = 'loan'
GROUP BY a.bank_name;
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked.